# Group by and sorting before a where clause?

Tags: sql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
ID   parent   ticket   category   _record_status   _log_user   _log_timestamp         _log_type 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1        1        1          active           1           2012-01-29 15:49:21    create
2    1        1        1          deleted          1           2012-01-29 15:52:14    destroy
3    3        1        2          active           1           2012-01-29 15:58:43    create
```

I want to be able to select all records that are not deleted for a specified ticket. However, this is difficult because of the revision system.

Is there a way to do this via SQL that is efficient, or would it be better to just do this in PHP, considering each ticket will only have a few records on average. I doubt any ticket would ever get more than 100 records in it's lifetime.

Comment: I really don't understand your description. Given your example data, what would your desired output be? (I assume you don't just want `SELECT * FROM ____ WHERE ticket = ___ AND _record_status <> 'deleted'`?)

Comment: You need a bit more detail about why the revision system makes this hard? expected output from your sample might help.  As it stands select * where ticket = 1 and _record_status <> 'deleted' would seem to do it...

Comment: Why can't you just use the 'where' clause?

Comment: Yeah, I was too busy thinking about the rest of my tables to realize this one is actually quite easy. I'll repost my question with a different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from YourTable
where _record_status <> 'deleted'
and ticket = @yourTicketId
```

Is that what you're looking for??

Comment: I think it's more complicated since it looks like a record can be deleted and undeleted.  See my answer (using exists)

Comment: @Shark This actually would work for this specific table, but I have other tables where there are actual revisions. For some reason I was overthinking this one....

Answer (score 1):

Sql!

```
SELECT .....
FROM .....
WHERE _record_status!="deleted" AND ticket=X
```